# Mobile Roaming Charges in Europe - have they been abolished yet?

Tags: eu, mobile-operators, roaming

I am currently based in Friedrichshafen, Germany. I have a German sim card. I will be travelling to Switzerland, Austria and France during this Christmas season and I would like to know if the European Union has passed laws abolishing roaming charges within these regions (EU countries). I have read a few [articles](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/oct/27/europe-abolishes-mobile-phone-roaming-charges) and [wiki links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations)  similar to these but can anybody provide an authentic source?

I use a sim card purchased from *Media Markt*. However, on my phone, it shows the service provider in Germany as *Vodafone*. My partner uses a *Lebara* sim card. Answers specific to these service providers would be helpful. I tried contacting the service providers but I have not got any conclusive replies from them. They told me that I will receive some sort of notification (either through sms or e-mail) about how things would be but I have not received anything.

Comment: Lebara is a Mobile virtual network operator. It doesn't run its own mobile network, rather it buys excess bandwith from true mobile networks such as vodafone. When using a MVNO operator your phone will often say the name of the network it is actually connected to rather than the company you are paying. I use lyca, which is similar to lebara, and it gives free roaming on calls and texts but doesnt have data roaming. When you go to a new country you will get a system generated text telling you the conditions.

Comment: Have you visited the provider's website?

Comment: You haven't received anything because you are not in roaming. You will receive sms as soon as you are in roaming area (within an hour usually).

Answer (score 6):

No. They were last lowered in April 2016 and will be completely abolished on June 15th 2017. In this link you can find the timetable for the changes: https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/roaming-tariffs